# Exception when changing data source to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to generate a query where I can find all entries that contain a specific order. So I've got it working with linq2entities but when attempting to run it against the linq2sql I have to change it to a left outer join and then apply a distinct. Something I don't want to do.

Linq2Entities:

```
List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>
{
new Order{ Id=1, Name="Order1"},
new Order {Id=2, Name="Order2"}
};

List<Product> Products = new List<Product>
{
new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Sugar", OrderId = 1 },
new Product {Id=2, Name="Flour", OrderId=1},
new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Milk", OrderId = 2 },
};

var query = (from order in Orders
join product in Products
on order.Id equals product.OrderId
into orderproducts
select new
{
User = order,
Roles = orderproducts
}).ToList();

var xx = query.Where(x => x.Products.Any(x => x.Name == "sugar"));// will produce a list of orders containing sugar.
```

I've now changed the 2 lists to be database Entities and constructed the relevant tables but I get a SQL error....

```
InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Order>
.GroupJoin(
outer: DbSet<Prpduct<string>>,
inner: product => order.Id,
outerKeySelector: product=> product.orderId,
innerKeySelector: (p, o) => new {
...
})' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

Comment: how do you get lists of `Orders` and `Products` from db?

Comment: Via the database context. Is important to note that I’m trying not to use navigation properties for this. 

So I’ve got 2 entities which are pretty much the same declaration has the 2 classes above. 

So I’m using the same linq has above but it’s generating the error. Obviously this would work if I put .toList before executing the linq query but I want it running against the database.

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not generate an error like that. Please be exact in stating which technology you use. Also, shouldn't you have a many-to-many relationship between Product and Order?

Comment: The many to many would be correct if you took it literally but my constraint is a order has many products. A 1:N relationship. That’s what I’m trying to get working. Don’t get too focused on the order and products relationship. I’m trying to get a 1 to many back 

Eg. 

Order 1 as a list containing its products

It’s using ef and dot netCore 3.1

Comment: So this is one of the many many questions on exceptions when grouping in EF core. Please find other questions on this topic. It's simply not suported.

Comment: Ah I didn’t realise that ef doesn’t support groupings. I could have sworn that it did. Is there a work around besides doing tolist()?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have tables with `Orders` and `Products`. There is a one-to-many relation between Orders and Products: every Order has zero or more Products, every Product belongs exactly to one Order, namely the Order that the foreign key `Product.OrderId` refers to.

Whenever you want to query items with their zero or more sub-items, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or as in your case Orders with their Products, consider to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-5.0), or the corresponding `IQueryable` version if you data is fetched from another process.

Although your code example doesn't say so, the error message gives me the impression that you are in fact using GroupJoin.

To fetch Orders with their Products:

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = ...
IEnumerable<Product> products = ...

var queryOrdersWithTheirProducts = orders.GroupJoin(products,

    order => order.Id,            // from every Order take the primary key
    product => product.OrderId,   // from every Product take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector:
    // From every Order, with all its zero or more Products make one new:
    (order, productsInThisOrder) => new
    {
        Order = order,
        Products = productsInThisOrder.ToList(),
    });
```

Quite often the requirement is: give me properties ... of Orders, with properties ... of their Products. In that case you should use the following `resultSelector`:

```
(order, productsInThisOrder) => new
{
    // Select the requested Order properties:
    Id = order.Id,
    Date = order.Date,
    ...

    // Select the Ordered Products:
    Products = productsInThisOrder.Select(product => new
    {
        // again: select only the requested properties
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name,
        Price = product.Price,
        ...
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

Now you really have an object that represents: `Orders with their Products`.

To get the Orders that have at least one Product with Name "Sugar" in it:

```
string productName = "Sugar";

// keep only the Orders that have at least one Product with Name "Sugar"
var ordersWithSugar = queryOrdersWithTheirProducts
    .Where(order => order.Products.Where(product => product.Name == productName)
                         .Any());
```

In words: from the sequence of Orders with their Products, keep only those Orders, that have at least one Product with a Name that equals productName.